# Does the recoil pattern change when peeking around walls?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

Hello I've got a question about Rainbow Six Siege.

In this game you have the ability to lean to your left or right to peek around a wall and you are able to shoot while doing so. My question is if shooting my weapon changes the recoil pattern?

I can imagine if you hold the gun diagonally, it will kick in a different way. Does the recoil pattern change in Rainbow Six Siege or will the gun just kick upwards as usual?

Answer (score 6):

Tested this out just now and it looks like the recoil pattern does not change. It still goes straight up relative to the ground, even if you peek.

Comment: "Straight up" relative to the ground or your point of view?

Comment: @deadly To the ground. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.